# Not sure what to put in my main to get my code to work

Tags: c++, function, loops

I wrote this code but not sure what to put in my main(), I tried my best to try and figure it out, if someone would please tell me what to do.
Here exactly what I am trying to do:

- Program describes what its suppose to do
- Prompts the user to enter a number between 1 and 10, and then fills an array with positive floating point number
- Outputs the contents of an array of floats, using a function
- Use a function to compute the mean, max and min from an array of floats. The values are returned in pass by reference variables
- Output the computed value
- If at any point the user enters an invalid input, prompt them again
- Terminates safely

Here is the code:

```
//include go here
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cfloat>

using namespace std;


//Constants go here
const int MAX = 10;
const int MIN = 1


//outputs overview of program to user 

void displayOverview();



//prompts user to enter a number between min and max and return it
//validated using a loop

int getIntInRange(int min, int max);



//prompts user to enter a floating point number that is > 0
//validated using a loop

float getPositiveFloat();



//prompts user for size of array (< size)
//fills nums with that many floating point values

int fillArray(float nums[], int size);


//outputs the array

void printArray (float arr[], int Size);



  //Computes and returns the mean, maximum, and minimum

void computesValues(float arrr[], int size, float &mean, float &max, float &min);



int main(){

  displayOverview();


  float myArr[MAX];
  int size = fillArray(myArr, MAX);

  return 0;
}


//Prompt user to enter a number between Min and max
//If user entered a number within the range, is valid is true
//If user entered a number not within min and max, output sorry not in range

int getIntInRange(int min, int max){

  int userInput = -1;
  bool isValid = false;
  while(!isValid){

    printf("Please enter an integer between %d and %d\n", min, max);

    scanf("%d", &userInput);
    if(min <= userInput && userInput <= max){
      isValid = true;
}else{
  printf("Sorry, that is not in range\n Please try again\n");
}
  }

  return userInput;
}


//int numVals
int fillArray(float nums[], int size){

  int numVals = getIntInRange(MIN, MAX);

  for(int i=0; i< numVals&& i<size ; i++){

    nums[i] = getPositiveFloat();

  }


  return numVals;
}

//Prompt user to enter a positive number
//if User enters a number that is not positive, output "Not a Positive"
float getPositiveFloat(){

  float input;
  do{
    cout << "Please enter a positive number\n";
    cin >> input;
    if(!(input>0)){
      cout << "Not a positive!\n";

    }

  }while(!(input>0));

  return input;


}


//Introduction to the program
void displayOverview(){

  cout << "Welcome to my program. You will see how magically I can compute things " << 
"from numbers!!" << endl;

}


//Print an array
void printArray(float arr[], int size){

  for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }
}


//Compute Min, max and mean.
void computesValues (float arr[], int size, float &mean, float &max, float &min){
  float sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
    sum = sum + arr[i]; 
  }
 mean = sum/size;
 max = arr[0];
 for (int i = 1; i<size; i++){
   if(arr[i] > max)
        max = arr[i];
 }
 min = arr[0];
 for (int i = 1; i<size; i++){
   if(arr[i] < min)
        min = arr[i];
 }
 printf("mean = %f max = %f min = %f\n", mean, max, min)

 }
```

Comment: "Ever time I write a code in my main..." I don't see the keyword `main` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Please post the entire error you are getting.

Comment: ***its giving me errors and warnings*** This part is what we can help you with if you let us. Add the text of the error message to your question. Showing  us the assignment and your whole program and asking us to try to figure out what you have done wrongly is not a good question for StackOverflow. It is very doubtful that this would help anyone in the future solve a specific problem. Remember that is the main purpose of StackOverflow helping users in the future with the same problem.

Comment: Your next step is to call printArray().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main does not call to compute the values from your array.

> ```
> void computesValues (float arr[], int size, float &mean, float &max, float &min)
> ```
>
> Should make the last 3 Float variables local to the function and remove them from the prototype and declaration:
>
> ```
> void void computesValues (float &arr[], int size){
> float mean{}, max{}, min{};
> ```

You can call the printArray function should take const references of min, max, mean, array, and size variables.

```
     void computesValues (float arr[], int size){
    float min{}, max{}, mean{};
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        sum = sum + arr[i]; 
    }
    mean = sum/size;
    max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i<size; i++){
        if(arr[i] > max)
        max = arr[i];
    }
    min = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i<size; i++){
        if(arr[i] < min)
        min = arr[i];
    }
    printArray(arr, size, mean, max, min); // call from within your computesValues function
}


//Print an array
void printArray(const float arr[], const int size, const float mean, const float max, const float min){

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    printf("mean = %f max = %f min = %f \n", mean, max, min);
}
```

The original errors with the code above:

1. `printf("mean = %f max = %f min = %f\n", mean, max, min); //<- typo added semi-colon`
2. `const int MIN = 1; //<-typo added semi-colon`
3. no declaration of variables min, max, mean in main.
4. const qualifier should be used for functions that do not modify the values
5. functions should only do one thing calc / print not both.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/hslnm5)

Comment: I don't think `printArray()` needed to be changed at all. Although I don't really understand why the OP had any problem the code needed in main() because its pretty much repeat what you have already done with `fillArray()`. Maybe the problem was just because of the errors. The OP originally mentioned errors then removed that from the question after we asked for the list of errors.

Comment: @drescherjm - IMO the `printArray()` function need the change as its inline with what it does print. The OP's errors were caused by those typos in the original code. With that said the point that the 3 variables were not declared the OP would incur errors when trying to call the function from within main.